# What is required to create local business rich-snippets complete with sitelinks AND breadcrumbs?

Tags: search-results, rich-snippets, sitelinks, structured-data, breadcrumbs

I have a local business directory site. I would like to markup my business listing 'profile' level pages for display as enhanced listings/rich-snippets complete with business names, addresses and phone numbers. I would also like to display site-links and path-based breadcrumbs to help users navigate site directory hierarchy (which is deep).

Is there a limit to the amount of breadcrumbs a site can leave? Is there a separate limit on the number of breadcrumbs which Google/Bing will display in the SERP? What kind of markup language(s) would be needed to best position my site to show site-links AND breadcrumbs?

For example:

> Find a business > Browse by Location > State > City > Zip >

or

> Find a business > Choose Service > Browse by location > State > City